# Export Dance Central Pictures

Tags: kinect, dance-central

How do you export the pictures/animated gifs from Dance Central?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Short Answer

You cannot export the pictures or videos created in Dance Central.

#### Long Answer

Microsoft Game Studios performed a survey with a [list of features that they were considering for Dance Central 2](http://www.insidekinect.com/2011/02/possible-dance-central-2-features.html). Among the list of possible features for the sequal is the ability to export and share these pictures/videos:

> #### Photo Sharing
>
> - Exporting pictures - Lets you export pictures taken during gameplay to your PC.
> - Exporting videos - Lets you export videos taken during gameplay to your PC.
> - Social Network picture sharing - Lets you export pictures taken during gameplay directly to social media networks such as Facebook.

This suggests that the ability to do so is not part of the first game.

[A post on GameSpot](http://www.gamespot.com/xbox360/puzzle/dancecentral/show_msgs.php?topic_id=m-1-57735924&pid=997631) indicates that the images remain in memory until you turn off the game, then are lost. Personal experience and research appears to support this theory. [A thread on the Dance Central support forums](http://www.dancecentral.com/forums/showthread.php?t=118) has posts that claim that you can access the saved images on your hard drive. I have confirmed, however, that there are no images that are accessible when you try to view either images on your XBox 360 or when you try to look for the game data in the memory section under *System Settings*. All you see is save game data.